# Getting error while sorting the mangoDB collection using Node.js and mangoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am getting the following error while fetching the record from MongoDB using Node.js and Mangoose.

> Error:

```
Error: 12-05-2020 08:20:33 - MongoError: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/anil/Desktop/new/EdQart_Project/local/edqart-store-setup-api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:460:61)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
const filters = this._getOrdersFilterParams(req);
const sort = this._getOrdersSortingParams(req);//{"CreatedAt":"desc"}

const orders = await collection.find(filters).sort(sort);
```

I am explaining my model file below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Float = require('mongoose-float').loadType(mongoose),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    {
        ORDERS_COLLECTION
    } = require('../utils/constants.util');

const ModelOrders = new Schema({
        OrderNumber: { type: String },
        OrderStatus: { type: String },
        OrderType: { type: String },        
        DispatchPriority: { type: String },

        Comments: { type: Array },
        Products: { type: Array },

        Customer: { type: Object },     
        TotalDiscount: { type: Object },
        TotalShipping: { type: Object },
        TotalCoupon: { type: Object },
        TotalAmount: { type: Object },
        PaymentDetails: { type: Object },
        ClientDetails: { type: Object },

        FocusSync: { type: Boolean },
        IsActive: { type: Boolean }
    }, 
    {
        timestamps: { 
            createdAt: 'CreatedAt', 
            updatedAt: 'UpdatedAt' 
        },
        collection: ORDERS_COLLECTION
    }
);

ModelOrders.index({CreatedAt: 1}, { background: true });

module.exports = ModelOrders
```

I have done the indexing but still that issue is coming. I need to resolve this issue and fetch the record with sorting.

Comment: It is issue with your machine memory. I have faced same kind of issue when I was having many documents with less RAM. Solution is increase memory.

Comment: @VikasKeskar: Ok but when I am fetching record without sorting its working fine.

Comment: Without sorting it deals with less records, while you apply any filter or sort, it goes for checking all records.

Comment: @VikasKeskar: While googling some people are saying adding index it will resolve the issue but I added still same issue persist.

Comment: Try using [explain](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-explain) to see if it is actually using that index.